# What interface should I choose to extend Yamaha LS9-32 outputs?

Tags: mixer, hardware, digital, interface, adat

I need more outputs on Yamaha LS9-32 so I am looking for an interface to extend outputs via ADAT output. I have MY16-AT card in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an inexpensive option, you could go for 2x [Behringer ADA8200](http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Computer-Audio/Audio-Interfaces/ADA8200/p/P0ATL).

Such two interfaces will allow you to use all 16 Ins and Outs on the MY16-AT.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked extensively with the LS-9 and have used the optical ports to extend the inputs/outputs a few times. We had a an older [MOTU 828](http://www.motu.com/products/motuaudio/828x) (mark 2 I think) that we used with good success with our LS-9. If you need [24 more outputs the 24A0 from MOTU](http://www.motu.com/products/avb/24ai-24ao) may do the job but i dont remember what the mac you can connect to the LS-9 is.

I may be able to offer more if you can specify why you need the extra inputs.

Comment: The poster needs extra outputs, not inputs...possibly to address a large or complicated sound system, or I guess possibly to record off the board in multitrack into a separate system.

Comment: my apologies, the 828 will work for outputs as well (and I have used it as such)